# cloud portability

Tags: google-app-engine, vmware, amazon-ec2, spring-roo

may i know how portability is gae application. let say i have an 
application that using comet feature, task queue..etc and not using 
bigtable and i want to deploy on vmware/amazon will it run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AppScale](http://code.google.com/p/appscale/) is designed for this kind of portability.

> AppScale is a platform that allows
>   users to deploy and host their own
>   Google App Engine applications. It
>   executes automatically over Amazon EC2
>   and Eucalyptus as well as Xen and KVM.
>   It has been developed and is
>   maintained by the RACELab at UC Santa
>   Barbara. It supports both the python
>   and java Google App Engine platforms.

Can't say for sure if it's something that will work for you but it's probably worth looking into.

Answer (score 1):

No. Google App Engine and Amazon Cloud Services have different APIs.

Many of the concepts are similar; it would certainly be possible to port many applications between the two and achieve similar functionality - but you'd have to modify a lot of code. If you have a lot of data stored in one system, you'd have to write custom code to export it from that system and import it into the other, too.